# Share a global structure between two files (in C)

Tags: c, file, structure, share, global

I have two files, main.c and hash.c

In hash.c, I only have one empty hash table which is called `hashtable` and some functions (not the main)
and in main.c, I have the main() function and the `#include "hash.h"`

My question is, if in main.c, I call a function from the hash.c like : `hash_add("strawberry", 3)`, which adds a key with its element in the hash table of the hash.c (which is called `hashtable`),

Then if I do `extern hash * hashtable` in the main.c will my 3 strawberries be in hashtable ? Or will my hashtable be empty ?

(What I think is when I call `hash_add("strawberry", 3)`, my 3 strawberries are in hashtable as long as I am within the scope of the function)

Thank you

Comment: If you have `hash *hastable;` in hash.c, you have to write `extern hash *hashtable;` in every other file you want to use the variable.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this in C.  It sounds like you are using global variables so I'll describe that first.  A better way is to use local variables and I'll show you that second:

With global variables you'd do something like this:

```
// hash.h
void hash_add(const char* key, int value);
extern hash h;

// hash.c
hash h;
void hash_add(const char* key, int value) { ... }

// main.c
#include "hash.h"
int main()
{
    hash_add("strawberry", 3);
    // h will now have three strawberries
}
```

It's best not to use global variables because you'll get fewer name clashes, and you can have more than one hash table at a time.  In that case, you'd normally hold a pointer to a hash and then pass it into the hash functions:

```
// hash.h
void hash_add(hash* h, const char* key, int value);
hash* hash_create();
void hash_destroy(hash* h);

// main.c
#include "hash.h"
int main()
{
    hash* h = hash_create();

    hash_add(h, "strawberry", 3);
    // h will now have three strawberries

    hash_destroy(h);
}
```